# Sql syntax to create hash

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, concatenation, md5

i am having a little trouble to create Hashes with my query.
I was trying with MD5 CONCAT But i keep getting errors

```
UPDATE table_name WHERE hash IS NULL SET hash = MD5(CONCAT(client_id,client_email));
```

I want to generate Hashes into the "hash" row, it currently has all values set as NULL.
Could someone correct me, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste your `ERROR` information here?

Comment: "i keep getting errors" is *not* a good problem description. Errors include helpful information. Even if *you're* struggling to decode that information, at least give *us* a fighting chance by including the full text of any error messages.

Comment: Having said that, I'm sure in this case you were advised to check the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) (Link to 5.7 version, other versions at other pages). Have you actually checked the manual before posting here?

Comment: You mixed up the order of where and set clauses.

Comment: @Shadow can you make that as a Separate answer, you solved my problem and i would like to select yours as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get some error :
The correct syntax is :

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET column1 = X WHERE Y
```

In your case

```
UPDATE tv20_clients SET hash = MD5(CONCAT(client_id,client_email)) WHERE hash IS NULL ;
```

Be careful you are not managing the null case here, this should be better :

```
UPDATE tv20_clients
SET hash = MD5(CONCAT(COALESCE(client_id,'0'),COALESCE(client_email, '0')))
WHERE hash IS NULL ;
```